# AWS Route53 2 isp's with fail over Configuration not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a non aws server with two public ip's configured. Both ip's can get the server simultaneously. I created a host zone for this server. I Set A record with one public ip as primary(active) with fail-over policy associated it with a health check and configured the second public ip address as secondary(passive) in the fail-over policy with no health checks.

The problem is i'm  getting secondary(passive) ip with nslookup even though i set it as secondary and the primary health check is working fine. but why i'm getting the secondary while the primary is working fine?

Comment: can you share screenshot (hiding ip) of your configurations ?

Comment: Primary: 
https://www.miarec.com/files/doc-img/amazon_aws/Route53_a_record_recordings_primary.png

SECONDARY:
https://www.miarec.com/files/doc-img/amazon_aws/Route53_a_record_recordings_secondary.png

I've configured like this..

Comment: it is configured correctly see this screenshot which shows primary IP when i used mxtoolbox for this : https://ibb.co/dsc7tU

Comment: thats just an example with same configuration like mine. In my environment i configured two public ip's to a server through NAT in my firewall so both ips can reach the server and route53  for dns purpose. Can you tell  me how to set a single public ip as primary and second public ip as secondary. The think is i'm using  two ISP's for internet connectivity if one isp gets down route53 needs to route the traffic through the secondary isp's pulic ip to the same server. Thats what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: test the results from mxtoolbox and see what results occur.

Comment: the issue is when i test the result i'm getting secondary ip. I should get primary ip. I have a doubt once route53 switched to secondary ip will it get switched to primary ip after it starts working.

Comment: If the health checks passes it will pass switch to primary again